# Alternatives To Apple Dock - Taskbar

Tags: macos, dock

This box helps explain the association that I always have had.

[image]

We bought a Mac.  I like many parts about it.  It syncs with my iphone etc...

I can't learn the dock.  I am afraid we might need to move back to Windows.  I can't stand it.  I've tried explaining to myself how to minimize it into the corner and **tried minimizing applications to icon**, but no luck.

### Is there an application to display a list?  I'm not looking for alternative techniques for understanding.  I really needs a list, not a dock.

Preferably it would work look similar to Windows Dock.

Having used applications like *Quicksilver* before, and knowing the ingenuity and geniuses in the Mac community it feels like someone could create something like this.

Comment: I wonder about her trying to use Launchpad? That way, you would clean off the dock - completely - except for Finder, which you can't remove, and the Launchpad icon. Then the programs that are open will appear down in the dock. Just a thought. Obviously, you have BootCamp if all else fails as well.

Comment: How did she solve the "two Word documents" situation in Windows? If you are looking for an app to mimic the Windows Taskbar we should know in detail how she worked through the different Use Cases during the day.

Comment: If it's just a matter of minimizing, what about going to System Preferences > Dock and **un**-checkmarking "Minimize windows into application icon"? That keeps every window separate. *I'm still thinking out loud here.*

Comment: @bassplayer7 I believe it has more to do with having a 1 click always correct location to bring up the window.  For example if she had a Microsoft Word windows open "Word Document 1" and "Word Document 2" She could always click "Word Document 1" in the taskbar to bring up the window no matter if she minimized, maximized, etc.  In mac osx she can't make the linkage so well because the same icon can represent 3 Microsoft Windows applications open.  Additionally there isn't any text anywhere to remind of what she does have open.

Comment: @William I understand absolutely what we both can't stand! You shouldn't force your self to use mac, computers should fit users not the opposite way.

Comment: Use expose. Or click on the application, then click window up the top.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[uBar](http://brawersoftware.com/products/ubar) is a Windows-style taskbar for OS X that I developed. Be sure to set **Window Grouping** to **Never** in the preferences, and it will exactly replicate the behaviour you are looking for.

[image: uBar taskbar for Mac]

Comment: Is there a way to prevent this from showing Finder all the time even when you have no Finder windows open?

Comment: @William Yes: Preferences, Apps, Exclude apps with zero windows.

Answer (score 5):

**This answer only works for older OS versions (<=10)**

**[DragThing](http://www.dragthing.com/)** is a commercial application that can display a list of running applications. It can be configured to create a Windows-like taskbar.

1. Click the  in the topleft corner, click Dock, then click Left or Right to move the dock to left or right. (so it won't get in the way of the Windows-like taskbar you are going to create, while you can still use it as a handy app launcher.)
2. [Download DragThing](http://www.dragthing.com/english/download.html) (thanks to [this page](http://www.iwebss.com/tech/361-pc-style-windows-taskbar-on-mac-os-x) for telling me about it) . It costs US $29 but you can try it for free. However, if you like it [you should buy it](http://www.dragthing.com/english/register.html).
3. Open the downloaded DMG file, drag the DragThing icon to the applications folder, delete the DMG file, open the applications folder (or Launchpad if you have Mountain Lion) and open DragThing.
4. Make sure DragThing is the active application (It says "DragThing" next to the  in the topleft corner then), press ⌘+0 and close all the DragThing windows except the one that appeared when you pressed that.
5. Right click on the window that appeared when you pressed ⌘+0 and click Rotate.
6. Drag it to the center of the bottom of the screen.
7. Right click again on it and click "Dock settings...".
8. Set the following (got most of it from [this page](http://www.iwebss.com/tech/361-pc-style-windows-taskbar-on-mac-os-x)):

> Set "Float Dock Window" to Always
>
> Turn "Show Window Title Bar" off
>
> Set "Icon Size" to 16×16
>
> Set "Spacing" to 0
>
> Set "Width" to about 70
>
> Set "Show Item Names" to Right
>
> Turn "Use Single-Click To Open Items" on (can be found at Advanced tab)
>
> Turn "Lock position" on (can be found at Advanced tab)
> 9. Close the window
> 10. Enjoy your shiny new taskbar! Eventually right click it and select a new color.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Outstanding! This post is very helpful. I'd give it 100 up-votes.

Comment: How can you display actually windows open like you have it and not docks icons?

Comment: @William What do you mean? What does it look like for you?

Comment: My computer just what it represented basically by the dock icons.  Example here in pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuuJU.png

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [Hyperdock](http://hyperdock.bahoom.com/) helps. It shows thumbnails of all open program windows when resting the mouse pointer on a dock icon. One can click on a thumbnail in order to bring the respective window to the front.

[image: Screenshot]

I cannot live without. Available from the app store.

Answer (score 2):

A 32 bit app for Mojave and lower was [DragThing](http://dragthing.com)

It will not work for current OS and is not open sourced or available for sale now.

---

Here is some more information about DragThing, in addition to com. BOY's answer.

I have owned and used this program for more than ten years. There is a free trial; the app costs US $29.

Among other features, DragThing can be configured to display a floating **"Process Dock"**, a panel of the icons of applications that are currently open and running -- and only the ones currently running. Unlike the Dock, it *does not* show icons of applications that are *not* running right now. (You can create other panels or docks to display tabbed groups of icons of frequently-used applications that you want to launch.)

[image]

You can position **DragThings' Process Dock** on the bottom of the screen if you want; I have it in the upper-right corner of my screen. Visually, you can choose from many different color schemes and designs. I chose the "heads-up-display" translucent black design.

In the "Process Dock", clicking on one of these open application icons will immediately bring that application to the forefront. This is analogous to the bar at the bottom of the Windows desktop.

There are four kinds of panels or docks that DragThing can create:

- **Dock** to show tabbed multiple panels of your favorite apps organized
  and grouped any way you like
- **Disk Dock** to show connected hard disks, CDs and DVDs, and servers
- **Process Dock**, as I have discussed above
- **Window Dock** to show open application windows (your elderly relative might be able to use this too.)

DragThing is not designed to be "Windows-like". If anything, it resembles features of Mac OS 9, the "classic" MacOS. But I think it will do the trick.

DragThing has myriad configuration settings that you can customize; far too many. It's daunting. But once you figure out the features and configure it the way you want, it will just work.

I have used DragThing for more than ten years. I can't live without it.

Having configured everything I want in two DragThing panels: a Process Dock in the upper right-hand corner of my screen; and a tabbed icon panel on the bottom of my screen, **I subsequently banished Apple's Dock off the screen and I virtually never use or look at Apple's Dock anymore.**

Here is a [review of DragThing from MacWorld Magazine](http://www.macworld.com/article/2025380/apps-we-cant-live-without-dragthing.html) from two months ago.

If you can't figure out how to configure DragThing to function like you want, you can email the developer, James Tomson, for tech support.

Answer (score 1):

[DockShelf](http://www.thealchemistguild.com/dockshelf) is a general Dock replacement and can be used to add *process docks* to any side of the screen (shown at different sizes, styles and as a tab in the screen shot).

I use Windows on and off for short periods of time and managing windows is a problem for me also so I'd recommend not minimizing windows at all but instead hiding an application (command-H) when you're not using it.

When you select another application using any of the dock methods mentioned, all the windows will appear on screen at once.

[image]

In the interest of full disclosure I am the developer of DockShelf.