# Is there a dock for switching between windows?

Tags: macos, dock, windows

Is there a feature or an add-on for OS X that lists the current app's open windows for quick visual switching?

The way I envision it is in the form of a second dock, say on the right-hand or left-hand corner of the screen.

A similar question was asked [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80106/alternatives-to-apple-dock-taskbar), but the HyperDock answer doesn't work for me. I am looking for a visual list that is available always, not just on hover.

Another question points out [Fantastisk](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/28378/fantasktik). This looks perfect, but the product has been discontinued and it seems unclear whether it even supports 10.8.

> Edit: [Witch](https://itunes.apple.com/app/witch/id412485838?mt=12) seems to come close, I'll try it out. I would *still* prefer a permanently visible list.

Comment: What is wrong with using F3 ?

Comment: I loved your little guy, so I copied it to my name ! hope you do not mind.

Comment: @Buscar sure, no problem! F3 shows a stacked view of multiple windows of an app - definitely not what I need.  Can this be configured? (I'll take a look in the settings.) I sometimes have 10 browser windows with 3 tabs each for repetitive tasks, and I need the ability to directly jump to one of them using the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ⌘` to switch between windows in the current application and ⌃F4 to switch between windows on the current space. And you can use an application like Alfred to [assign shortcuts to applications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/can-i-create-a-shortcut-to-open-a-specific-application-on-os-x/20116#20116).

[Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) is one of the most popular window-based Dock / command-tab alternatives. See these questions for other options:

- [Best app to switch between all open windows (alternatives to Witch)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2718/best-app-to-switch-between-all-open-windows-alternatives-to-witch)
- [Switch between windows on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/45310/switch-between-windows-on-mac-os-x)